# Are there any disadvantages of using a version number with four parts (ww.xx.yy.zz)?

Tags: nuget

The NuGet docs [state that](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-basics)

> A specific version number is in the form Major.Minor.Patch[-Suffix]

and that NuGet supports Semantic Versioning. However, the same article [also contains examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-basics) with version numbers consisting of four parts and in fact, there are some [relatively](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/4.5.2.1) [widely](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/1.0.109.2) [used](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/15.0.4795.1000) packages with such version numbers.

So, are there any disadvantages of using a version like 1.0.0.1 for a NuGet package?

My concrete use case is a database driver where I want the driver version to include the version of the database which already consists of three parts. Using a four part version would leave the last part for the driver itself and the first three are simply the database version it is compatible and tested with.